# Automatic Check-(In/Out)

Tags: starteam

Is it possible to setup a StarTeam repository that automatically checks in and checks out code? Would I have to write code that checks (in/out) through the command line, or is there an option in the software itself?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the commandline tool (stcmd)
The command for checking in is stcmd ci and the command for checking out is stcmd co.

Here is the documentation:
http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.stcmdtools.doc/STARTEAM-57C20EC2-CLIENTCOMMANDLINEOPERATIONSJUMPOFF.html?cp=8_3_2

There is also an official forum for more general usage questions

[ST Forum](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/starteam/f/)

Comment: Where is the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure why but the link was stripped out. I have edited it back in.