# Borland Star Team - Check out timing is too much

Tags: starteam

I have different versions of my project e.g. **SeleniumTool_1.1**, **SeleniumTool_2.2**, **SeleniumTool3.3** etc... and each having different version in star team as well named as - SeleniumTool_1.1, SeleniumTool_2.2, SeleniumTool3.3.

But the folder name (in my local system) that should be **`SYNC`** with Star Team is "**SeleniumTool**".

**The issue is -** `Every time I switch between different version of project, it shows me every file as a modified, even if hardly 1 or 2 files has been modified. And it takes nearly 2 to 3 hours to take all files' latest version.`

Can someone guide me through this that how can I manage this issue?

Comment: .. alternatively to BalaclavaBivvy's answer, you might be able to **Update** all files first, to reconcile what's actually changed, and then you'll be able to identify the 1 or 2 and only check out those?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify what exact approach you are taking.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but my assumption is that you are doing the following:

You are changing the working folder path for a given view each time you want to check out a particular release.

This mostly bypasses StarTeam and causes the need for unnecessary checkout.

What I'd recommend doing is using a fixed view for each release. Your structure would be as follows

[View structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmm1Y.jpg)

Development work is carried out in the child view (i.e SeleniumTool 3.3 for example). Once the version is ready for release, it is promoted into the root view using View Compare Merge (promote).

Each view has its own independent working folder on your local machine

Then when its time to start a new release, a new view is created off root.

This has the advantage of ensuring that only modified files need checked out. If you need to move changes into other views, use VCM replicate (between siblings) promote (to push up to stable) or rebase (to bring new code down into a child view)

There is no need to play around with working folders.

There's a host of similar questions here on the StarTeam community forum: [Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984575/automatic-check-in-out/41853175)